# Use "for loop" to create newly named variables from the keys of a dictionary

Tags: python

I want to use a for loop to create newly named variables from the keys, which can then be retrieved globally down the road. To define the variable before with `None`, has unfortunately brought nothing. Also, with `Global` I did not get further, but possibly I used it also wrong. I have googled a lot, but unfortunately I couldn't get hold of the solution. Is there any trick how I can retrieve the new variables in the later course?

```
LAeq = { 'Januar': [69.1, 57.9, 58.3, 55.6],
         'Februar': [66.7, 65.5, 63.5, 62.4] }

anzahl_Januar = None #anzahl is number in English
print ("{:<9} {:<5} {:<9}".format('Monat','Tage','Prozent'))

for key in LAeq.keys():
    for value in LAeq[key]:
        anzahl_key = 0
        for i in LAeq[key]: #LAeq['Januar']
            if i > 63 :
                anzahl_key = anzahl_key + 1
    print("{:<9} {:<5} {:<9}".format(key, anzahl_key, "{:.1%}".format(anzahl_key/len(LAeq[key]))))
    
print(anzahl_Januar)
```

Obviously the dictionary is much larger, I just put down an example here. I am thankful for any advice! :)

Comment: Why would you want a set of variables called `anzahl_Januar`, `anzahl_Februar` etc. instead of a dict with keys of `Januar`, `Februar`???

Comment: @Nick Unfortunately this is the assignment I got from my programming class. Afterwards they want to check, if the numbers are correct like `anzahl_Januar = 1` etc. Yeah, so I don't really have a choice.

Comment: In the code, for which values do you want variables to be created? `anzhal_key` ?

Comment: one way to go would be `eval`uating or `exec`uting generated code

Comment: @RohitBabu Yes correct, so in the end I want to be able to `print(anzahl_Januar, anzahl_Februar)`

Comment: So, the point of having variables is to be able to print their values? If yes, do you need it in any specific pattern?

Comment: @LMD OK, thanks for your suggestion. I will read about these functions later.

Comment: @RohitBabu Yes, within the exercise there is a block I can't change, it looks something like this `assert anzahl_Januar < 2`. I don't know what "assert" stands for, probably something they made up. So they want this part to work, it's kind of a mandatory field. It's better if I ask my trainers on Monday, what exactly they want, because it seems kind of stupid to do that.
Thank you very much so far anyway! I will give an Update on Monday evening then.

Comment: Okay. `assert` is basically validating `anzahl_Januar` to be less than 2. It's a testcase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the exec command, like this:

```py
dict={}
for i in range (10):
    key=str("x"+str(i))
    dict[key]=i
for key,value in dict.items():
    exec(f'{key}={value}')
```

Try adjusting this to your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I inserted `exec(f'anzahl_{key}={anzahl_key}')` at the end of the second "for loop" and it works greatly! :)